# Will this app damage my computer?

Tags: macos

I've downloaded an application but when I want to open this application it shows an error message saying that it will damage my computer.

I tried to download the application from multiple sources but it continues to give me the same message. When I try to open the application with my right mouse button it still gives me the same message.

[image: error message]

I have the last open beta of OS X El Capitan if that matters. If anyone knows how I can still open it, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is GateKeeper doing its thing.

Try slackening off the security a little bit; go to **Security & Privacy** prefpane, and change `Allow apps downloaded from:` to a more lax setting (you may need to choose Anywhere, I'm not sure if Atlassian qualify under "identified developers").

Comment: Also if you do a search for "sorcetree" there are no warnings about this app on the first page. So Cesium is likely right, it's just the OS telling you to be careful because it wasn't downloaded from the App Store

Comment: No, this is the message used when the bundle does not match its code signature. Whether it is infected, blacklisted by Apple, or just a mistake on Atlassian's part isn't easy to tell unless Atlassian says something. `codesign -vv SourceTree.app` will show what's changed if Xcode/Command Line Tools is installed.